# What is wrong with this code? It is only printing out the first letter of the user input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char char_name;
printf("Hello, what is your name? \n ");
char_name = getchar();
printf("Hello %c. Glad to meet you. \n", char_name);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It keeps printing out the first letter of the user input. I want to have it print out the entire string that the user enters

Comment: So you need to read the entire user input first. use a loop, or consider using `fgets()`.

Comment: The return value of `getchar` does not fit into a `char` variable

Comment: If you want to know why  `getchar()` only gets a single char, what (still, after reading the documentation) is unclear?

Comment: well you told it to print the first letter of user input

Answer (score 1):

Right now get char is only getting the first caracter of the string provided. You will need to create an array of chars to hold the string and use fgets to properly set it.

You can read the whole name by doing the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
    printf("Your name is %s.", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf()` is a very bad option.

Comment: @SouravGhosh good point, updated to use gets instead.

Comment: You made it worse. Use `fegts()`, there's no function called `gets()` in the standard anymore.